# Why is my Mindtex-generated normalmap rendering weirdly in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, node-editor, uv-image-editor, normal-map

[image: Normals not working.] Sample .blend [here](https://ufile.io/4mk8b).
Sorry, I imagine this is a fairly straightforward / dumb problem. I built a test normal map in [MindTex](https://store.steampowered.com/app/441770/MindTex_2/) from a greyscale pixel art height map. Testing the resultant map in Blender Cycles gives me some weird rendering issues, where identical (as far as I can tell) point lights at different sides of the column appear to render very different casts of light and shadow on individual faces.

The UV appears to be correct, the normalmap should be fine (it's a very simple map and MindTex has proven to be a useful tool in the past). If I disconnect the map in the material nodes, the problem fixes itself.

...What on earth is going on?

Appreciate any time you can give this. Looking forward to a solution...!

--Rev

Comment: Using the [normal map](https://i.imgur.com/WaS5th0.png) node seems to work as expected.

Comment: Yeah, I'm an idiot. Not used to TESTING normal maps in Blender. If you submit your comment as an answer I'll mark it correct and get back to banging my head on my desk. THANK YOU! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *[normal map](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/vector/normal_map.html)* node between your *image texture* node and your normal input. As you already have, the image texture should be set to **Non Color Data**.

[image: normal map node]

From the manual:

> The Normal Map node generates a perturbed normal from an RGB normal map image. This is usually chained with an Image Texture node in the color input, to specify the normal map image. For tangent space normal maps, the UV coordinates for the image must match, and the image texture should be set to Non-Color mode to give correct results.